# (jekyll) css won't render on github pages

Tags: github, themes, jekyll, github-pages

I want to use this theme on github pages, but css won't render (and also links in the menu are not working) when I open link https://urbanzrim.github.io
I've read that only few themes are supported by github pages. Is this true?

If not, can someone help me modify this theme to work? This is the repository of the theme: https://github.com/urbanzrim/airspace-jekyll. I know this was already a topic few times here, but I really don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Airspace-jekyll** is not really a theme, at least from what is known as a Jekyll theme.

It is a complete Jekyll site ready to edit your content and publish your posts.

As it says

> To start your project, fork this respository, put in your content, and go!

You just need to use it and upload all the files to Github following the instructions at https://pages.github.com .

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but page is without a style. There is something I am missing, but I don't have an idea what that is.

Comment: In `_config.yml`, change `baseurl: "/airspace-jekyll"` to `baseurl: "/"`.

Comment: You're right. Looks like I was too fast. Thank you very much. I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Nice, generally It may take few minutes to Github pages to show your latest changes.